# The Usage of "so" and "wie"

Tags: grammar, dialect, style

> ***So*** weit Sacramento auch sein mag, fährt er noch dahin.

However far Sacramento may be, he's still going to drive there.

> ***Wie*** stark mein bester Freund sein mag, kann er noch nicht dieses schweres Gewicht heben.

However strong my bestfriend may be, he still can't lift that heavy weight.

*So* and *wie* have the same meaning and they both mean *such* and *like that* but when it's combined with *auch* it becomes *however*. Is this sentence written in standard German or a regional dialect?

Comment: I would also write "**Wie** weit Sacramento [...]", even prefer it over *"So"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wie stark mein bester Freund sein mag, kann er noch nicht dieses
>   **schwere** Gewicht heben.

(little mistake there)

Also:

> Wie stark mein bester Freund **auch** sein mag, kann er *doch* noch nicht dieses schwere Gewicht heben.

You version is grammatically correct, it sounds very odd though.
With these additions you more clearly emphasize the contradiction between your friend being quite strong and his inability to lift the weight.
The first sentence is perfectly fine already. None of them are in a specific regional dialect.

Comment: In the first sentence there's also missing *doch*. And actually I would drop *noch* in both sentences.

Comment: Could you add some explanations about the original question on "however" in German? It's a bit hard to follow your answer for a non-native German speaker.

Comment: @Gigili I am not sure in which way the OP wishes to combine the words.
An example would be very helpful.

Generally I can only say, that "However" can be translated to "allerdings" 95% of the time.